# How to use forEach function in new version of Node.js too filter mongodb database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to display only name of cars from my small database by using .forEach method along with .find method but got error
TypeError: Car.find(...).forEach is not a function

Before this tried with call back function but newer version of mongodb doesn't support call back functionds any more

My whole is code is here just tried to connect nodejs app with my localhost and succesfully displayed the whole database in console but when tried to display only name of cars got stuck there

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/carsDB",{useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true});
 

const carSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    year: Number,
    make:String
    
});

const Car = mongoose.model("car", carSchema);
const elantra = new Car({
    name: "Elanta",
    year:  2020,
    make: "Hyundai"
});

const civic = new Car({
    name: "Civic Sport",
    year: 2023,
    make: "Honda"
});

Car.insertMany([elantra,civic]);
Car.find().forEach((car)=>{
  console.log(car.name);
});
```

```
Car.find().forEach((car)=>{
  console.log(car.name);
```

`TypeError: Car.find(...).forEach is not a function`

Comment: Do `const cars = Car.find()` and then `console.log(cars)`. What do you get?

Comment: I want to display car.name i can display whole database

Comment: Try `Car.find().toArray().forEach()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try putting the exec() with find():

```
Car.find({}).exec().
  then( cars => {
    cars.forEach( car => {
      //...
    })
  }).
  catch(err => console.error(err));
```

see more here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.find()

Comment: Got this error -> MongooseError: Query.prototype.exec() no longer accepts a callback

Comment: @HarmanjitSingh, updated my answer, took an old source

Comment: Thank you so much it works can you please what .exec is

Comment: @HarmanjitSingh, is used to execute the query, because you can add other functions together, such as the limit. If my answer is correct, can you mark it as solved?